# Test for empty nested array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
array(4) {
  [29] => NULL
  [31] => NULL
  [33] => NULL
  [35] => NULL
}
```

I would like to test all keys if all keys contain NULL values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(count(array_filter($input, 'is_null')) == count($input)) { 

}
```

should be what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// need php version >= 5.3 or you need to define a function, or just use a loop to check.
if (!count(array_filter($your_array, function($var){return $var !== null}))) {
  // all values is null.
}
```

Comment: I'm curious though, all along I thought you can't pass anything to `empty` other than a variable, is it allowed since `php >= 5.3?`

Comment: @SiGanteng Yep, I forgot that. You can only pass a variable. Thx for point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The mega easy way:

```
function allNULL($array){
  foreach($array as $i)
   if($i!=null) 
    return FALSE;
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: `array(0, 0, 0, null)` would fail this

Comment: if not all keys contain null, it's a fail. That's what he asked

Comment: Your code was doing `if($i)` though. So if I do `array(null, null, null)` it would return false when it's supposed to be true. But I see you changed it since. So nevermind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $filternull = function( $value ) {
       return $value !== null;
    }

    $remaining = array_filter( $yourarray, $filternull );

    echo count( $remaining ); 
    // === 0, if all were "null";
?>
```

Comment: Should be `$value !== null` for your filter function.